# Is there an English transitive verb meaning "to make someone/something valuable"?

Tags: single-word-requests, transitive-verbs, causative-verbs

I'm thinking something along the lines of "imbue" or "instill", but neither of those words work perfectly unless you append "with value".

Ideally this would be a word that's used in a subject/object context, i.e. [subject] ____ [object to be made valuable], so something like "appreciate" doesn't quite work.

"Enrich" is the best I've come up with, but I'm curious if there's anything more interesting.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127610/discussion-on-question-by-dekaliber-is-there-an-english-word-for-to-make-valuab). It is also the subject of [this meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15106), mostly because some people believe that adequate context and an example sentence has **already been provided by the OP**, but others disagree with this notion. Such discussion belongs there not here.

Comment: @dekaliber, I appreciate the support but, even though my answer didn't deserve any of the shade some of the locals threw at it, it really shouldn't be marked as the __best__ answer, either. As noted, the one I found is in the OED but only as an almost virtual word. Even _worthen_ has shown up at least once and _envalue_ apparently more than that, albeit no example currently provided really matches your sense.

Comment: @lly Haha, fair enough, though it answered my curiosity well. I didn't have a specific context in mind — this was more of a shower thought than anything else, so I appreciate you all for gamely humoring me. I admit that I was a bit surprised (and even slightly intimidated) by the amount of debate this attracted!

It struck me that we have a very obvious word for making something _less_ valuable ("devalue") but no clear equivalent for the positive. Before reflecting on what this says about society, I thought I'd check the wisdom of the crowds to see if I was missing something.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is one. No one uses it.

[**invalue**, *v.²*](https://oed.com/view/Entry/98915)

> *transitive*. To make valuable; to give value to.

Literally no one. The *OED* notes that, as far as it can tell, it has **only** shown up in dictionaries glossing Latin *invalidare* or filling things out as a possible coinage. It hasn't been seen in the wild.

Incidentially, it's even less useful than it looks at first glance. That ² is there because there's an [invalue, *v.¹*](https://oed.com/view/Entry/98914) which uses the other sense of the prefix *in-* to offer the exact opposite meaning: to reckon of **no** value or worth. That has (rarely) shown up in actual usage.

There are words for what you're trying to say but they're generally describing natural processes (interest and inflation naturally *accrue* or *grow*), recognizing the already intrinsic worth of something (antiques and mineral lodes can be *discovered*, *recognized*, *appreciated*, &c), or creating undeserved worth for untoward ends (*talk up*, *pump*, *gild*, &c). For all of those, though, the context needs to be clarified before the meaning will be clear. They won't have a simple abstract meaning of *to increase sth in value* on their own.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127609/discussion-on-answer-by-lly-is-there-an-english-word-for-to-make-valuable).

Answer (score 14):

**Valorize**.  The original term is adapted from the French *mettre en valeur*, but it has made its way into English, mostly in “international” writing (UN, OECD, etc.) where a noble sentiment must be expressed in multiple languages.

Here’s one of multiple dictionary references: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/valorize

If you read official documents written in Canada, you soon get accustomed to seeing *mettre en valeur* translated straight across as *valorize*,  and *mise en valeur* translated as *valorization*. People who prepare original drafts simultaneously in English and French tend to harmonize them, even if the wording ends up being stilted in one or both languages.

In many cases, strict equivalence in the reading of the translation is more important than literary style.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127608/discussion-on-answer-by-global-charm-is-there-an-english-word-for-to-make-valua).

Comment: The actual validating reference needs to be quoted. CD doesn't license for instance 'Tina's generosity with her time really valorises her.' OP's example sentences have been disappeared, of course.

Answer (score 13):

### endear (historically)

I've had to think of a popular [answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/19744) that I had once given - before closing my account - on StackExchange :
[Why do Russians call their women expensive (“дорогая”)?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19736/why-do-russians-call-their-women-expensive-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F)

In Old English *"dear"* (*deore*) meant ["precious, valuable; costly, expensive; glorious, noble; loved, beloved, regarded with affection"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dear).  In the 1580s *"to endear"* was recordedly used with the general meaning [*"to enhance the value of"*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/endear). Today you may still interpret *"to endear (somebody to someone)"* as *"to make (somebody) valuable (to someone)"*.

Admittedly this is of limited value a few centuries later, but you and other readers of the question might still consider it interesting.

Comment: Obviously, if something endears me to you, something makes you valuable to me. However, I doubt that is the OP's idea. Anyway, no samples were given.

Answer (score 9):

This is a good question, I think "Enhance" would be applicable in a lot of situations, though not a lot different to "Enrich".

Interestingly for the opposite action of devaluing something, there is "Abatement".

Though I can find no similar meaning for addition of value.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add appropriate evidential support, e.g. dictionary definitions (preferably with links), as we're looking for *detailed, authoritative answers* rather than unreferenced personal opinion. For further guidance, see [answer], or look at the some of the other upvoted answers. :-)

Answer (score 9):

It's a *hapax legomenon* [only attested once](https://oed.com/view/Entry/23038) and formed by analogy with *cheapen*, but

#### worthen

> To give worth to; value; make or become worth or worthy; appraise. (via [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worthen))

Comment: Why is everyone feeling like such gatekeeping boors today? (a) It's a new editor. Be nicer. (b) They _gave_ a source. If you consider this Wiktionary entry off, take it up with them and if you're right they'll fix it. That's what keeps them reputable. (c) [Here](https://oed.com/view/Entry/230383) is the OED entry, which is occasionally considered a reputable source.

Comment: Not all of us have access to paywalled sources. Please include the relevant extracts in the answer. Please.

Comment: Alright, finally got access to the OED: a single citation from the 19th century, and marked *obsolete* (relevant information NOT included in the answer) - hardly a likely candidate for use by OP.

Comment: It might be obscure, but I think a lot of people would understand the meaning.

Comment: It's not commonly used (I've never heard it used in conversation), but the accepted answer had no usages, so it seemed like worthen was at least on that footing. I worked backwards to find it -- I thought "enworthen" might be a word, and when I looked it up this came out as the correction.

Comment: Is there a style guide for answers on this site around expected information in answers like this? I think I've seen a lot of dictionary entry-only responses, but I might be misremembering.

Comment: @metaperture There is and you can find it at the bottom of the main page, but your answer was actually fine.

Answer (score 9):

[The OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/9787#eid275207) says it's a US usage, but *appreciate* should work just fine for you:

> 4. *Originally U.S.* Opposed to depreciate.
>    a. *transitive.* To raise in value.

They even give an example that fits your "*[subject] appreciates [object to be made valuable]*":

> The depreciation of gold, from its increased quantity, will appreciate silver in comparison with it.

Comment: It doesn't really work just fine since of course _appreciate_ is more generally understood as simply happening, whether in relation to recognizing intrinsic worth or as a result of general inflation. Even your example depends on a market action producing a corresponding action, rather than an agent causing the rise in value. Still, yeah, within certain contexts it'll work.

Comment: Also _orig. US_ implies that it's since spread more generally, in any case at least as far as Canada. =)

Comment: This answer works well if talking about increasing the financial value of a thing.

Comment: I definitely works, it just sounds quite awkward (since it's usually used differently) and could of course be misunderstood

Answer (score 7):

As tchrist (please correct me if I'm mistaken) mentioned in a comment, *envalue* is a word that, while not recorded in any dictionary, has seen actual use over the last hundred years and more with a meaning close to the one sought.

> The general principle is that refinement may both **envalue** and
> empower an artifact. (Real Spaces: World Art History and the Rise of
> Western Modernism; David Summers; Broadfoot Publishing Company,
> Morningside Bookshop, 1991)
>
> I stated to him that I regarded the war as a sectional one and to
> **envalue** principles. (Letter to Hon. J. J. Speed, Atton. Gen'l.; John A Campbell;  Southern Historical Society papers; Richmond,
> Virginia Historical Society, 1878)
>
> Let the judges include the artistry of the mount as part of their duty
> of selection but dismiss from consideration equipping every juror with
> a yardstick. Roofing is **envalued** by the square foot. Pictures are
> as the artist made them and framed them. He is the creator. The
> expression is his. (Camera craft; Photographers' Association of
> California; 1900)
>
> "He was sulking wasnt he Mommy?" the second son asks looking up into
> her warm wise face **envalued** with eyelid wrinkles of love and
> experience. (Prologos; Bayliss, Jonathan; Ashburnham, Mass. : Basilicum Press, 1999)
>
> A number of other items **envaluing** more than $5,000 could have been
> cited, but due to short allotment of time to complete the statement,
> it is believed that the items enumerated herewith will suffice to
> indicate the condition of the accounts for project No. 16. (Hearings
> Before the United States. U.S. Congress. Senate. Committee on
> interstate commerce, 1930)

It's even been used with people,

> This strange event is seen therefore as at once the affirmation of
> Universality (God is All) and of particularity (Jesus is **envalued**
> and endorsed as a singular, real, unrepeatable person, and therefore
> every singular person is envalued). (Meditation & reality : a critical
> view; Fox, Douglas A., 1927-2008; Atlanta, Ga. : John Knox Press,
> 1986)
>
> Fifth Columnists activities were publicized to a great exent, and the
> American people were made to realize the seriousness of a situation
> which **envalued** secret agents of foreign nations infestering the
> sanctity of the American home. (The Pow Wow, Apr. 8, 1948; Tyler
> Junior College)

However, this word would appear absolutely ridiculous in most of the blanks in question, saving perhaps the first.

> Its scarcity **envalued** the coin.
>
> His insight and
> experience **envalued** Old Joe.
>
> Their sensitivity to bad air **envalues** canaries in coal mines.
>
> Her cooking **envlaued** Granny.
>
> Granny was
> **envalued** by her cooking.
>
> Deeds not words **envalue** a
> leader.

In fact, this word exemplifies the issue with all of the words proposed so far - they are absolutely unwarranted in these contexts: using them would be to flaunt idiom and invite ridicule.

The natural choices are the ones in PerformanceDBA's answer.

Comment: Yes, this was the one I had thought of and had [mentioned in a chatroom comment to lly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58649811#58649811). I can't say that I would use it in most extended contexts myself, but it seems possible for the more direct application, perhaps as the antonym to *devalue*.

Comment: The examples don't show this word consistently being used in the desired sense. In many cases it is simply a synonym for "valued", which has a different meaning.

Comment: @MarkFoskey No matter, they still show that this word has seen more use than many of the others suggested, even if it is with varying senses.

Answer (score 6):

A common verb for this is *endow*. To be *endowed* is to be gifted with good attributes, properties, possessions and such. This is related to the noun *dowry*, which is essentially value added to a bride. In the transitive usage, it tends to require a *with*-complement though.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add appropriate evidential support, e.g. dictionary definitions (preferably with links), as we're looking for *detailed, authoritative answers* rather than unreferenced personal opinion. For further guidance, see [answer], or look at the some of the other upvoted answers. :-)

Answer (score 5):

***exalt***

To raise to a higher class, a higher degree of value or excellence; to dignify, ennoble. [According to definition e. of the [OED]](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65555?rskey=aSP2HO&result=3#eid)

> 1711   R. Steele Spectator No. 4. ⁋8   I shall not lower but *exalt*
> the Subjects I treat upon.

I am surprised this hasn't been suggested yet.  Seems like it fits perfectly.  To exalt someone is to raise them to a higher degree of value.

In fact, ***dignify*** and ***ennoble*** are also good synonyms given in the definition that could also work--I don't see that these have been suggested yet either.

Answer (score 0):

How about *furnish*?

This might work better in some contexts than in others. It doesn't really mean quite the same thing, more like bringing something into its most complete form, so it requires the furnish*er* to actually add something to the furnish*ee* in a  somewhat less abstract sense that just *adding value*.

It's also a bit old-fashioned since it's mostly used now to mean provide with furniture!

#### Some examples

> I hope these new recruits will furnish our company.

> I intend to save money by buying a bike in poor condition
> and furnishing it myself.

> The work experience will definitely furnish your CV.

#### Reference

OED (https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/75677?rskey=dYsDI3&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> furnish, *v.*
> ...
> **5.**
> **a.** *simply.* To supply with what is necessary.
> **b.** To decorate, embellish. *Obsolete.*
> ...
> **6.** *esp.* To prepare for work or active service; to equip (a person), caparison, harness (a horse), fit up (a weapon, etc.), fit out (a ship). *Obsolete.*

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add appropriate evidential support, e.g. dictionary definitions (preferably with links), as we're looking for *detailed, authoritative answers* rather than unreferenced personal opinion. For further guidance, see [answer], or look at the some of the other upvoted answers. :-)

Answer (score -3):

1. The problem is in your requirements.  The word you are seeking is one thing, but the specific usage you have given is really stilted, and English is not stilted.  Seeking one English word to fit your grid is not reasonable.
2. Further, a property (specific value) of a subject is not animate, thus it cannot *do* anything to the subject that has that property.  The thing is valued [by animate subjects] *for* the property.  Your examples are an attempt to bestow animation on properties, which mangles the language.
3. You want *value* to be included, but your sentences do not express *value* only, they express additional senses.
4. Last, you do not differentiate between a subject that has value, that is increased, and a subject that has no value, wherein value is conferred.

Corrected:

- *The scarcity of the coin caused its value to increase*
- *Old Joe was esteemed for his insight and experience*
- *Its sensitivity to bad air make canaries in coal mines invaluable*
- *Granny was endeared for her cooking*
- *Deeds, not words, make a leader*.

Comment: The question's examples which were added and removed are discussed in a [meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15106). This answer demonstrates that the original question is potentially unanswerable as there are many ways of doing so, depending on the nuance required. In that way, it's a good answer, although it may now need editing a little.

Comment: As evidenced, if the question had not been butchered, there would have been no confusion, no incorrect answers.  It would be good if the cause, not the symptom, was addressed.

Comment: The **cause** is best addressed by closing the question until the precise meaning required is made clear. But the community seems set against that course of action.

Comment: That is neither the problem, nor the cause.  If you honestly wish to address the issue, join us on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127609/discussion-on-answer-by-lly-is-there-an-english-word-for-to-make-valuable) or [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15106).